# Magnific jQuery image gallery plugin not working correctly only in one part of site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I am using the jQuery [Magnific](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) image gallery plugin in two places in exactly the same way on a site. It works perfectly [in one place](http://dev-teachourcities.pantheonsite.io/practices/making-tacos), and is broken [in the other](http://dev-teachourcities.pantheonsite.io/school/big-fat-school-east) (see the image gallery links in the sidebars)... it seems to be trying to do its thing but will not load in an overlay. Instead, it loads at the top of the window.

The gallery is being fired off like this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('.gallery_image_link').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        gallery:{
            enabled:true
        }
    });
});
```

The images in the gallery look like this:

```
<a href="/sites/default/files/styles/practice_gallery/public/big_img1.jpg" class="gallery_image_link" title="Pup"><img src="/sites/default/files/styles/practice_gallery_thumb/public/small_img1.jpg"></a>
```

Console in Chrome (or any other browser) does not provide any useful info. I expect that there is some kind of conflict with something else on the page... but what?

This is a Drupal site, but the Magnific library is not loading via any Drupal module. And again, works great in the first place... not so much in the second. I'm stumped!

Answer (score 0):

Kids, always remember to load the associated CSS along with the Javascript on every page where it will be needed. Yep. That's what it came down to; missing CSS. *Yeesh...*